# Why edittext not inflate text with settext()?

Tags: android

I am trying to set predefined text in `EditText` field but it is empty. Please take a look at the code

```
var yes: Button? = null
var no: Button? = null
private lateinit var title : EditText
private lateinit var description : EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_template)
    title = findViewById(R.id.dialog_title)
    description = findViewById(R.id.dialog_description)

    val lp = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
    lp.copyFrom(this.window?.attributes)
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    this.window?.attributes = lp

    yes = findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialogOkButton)
    no = findViewById<Button>(R.id.dialogCancelButton)
    yes?.setOnClickListener(this)
    no?.setOnClickListener(this)

    if (isEditMode){
        prepareUpdateData()
    } else {
        prepareEmptyData()
    }
}

private fun prepareEmptyData() {
    title.setText(toDoItem.title) // <--- HERE NOT WORKING
    description.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(toDoItem.description)--- HERE NOT WORKING
}
```

Comment: title.setText(toDoItem.title) // <--- HERE NOT WORKING
Are you sure that toDoItem.tittle has some string in it ? Maybe it's empty

Comment: Try title.setText("test"), does that print? If so the properties are empty.

Comment: @AshutoshOjha yes it has text inside. I checked in debugger

Comment: @Ricky no its not helping

Comment: Oh... the problem was in if/else condition i messed up methods